# Finding eigen values of special block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
$$
\left.\mathbf A=\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)_{7 \times 7}\right.
$$
I need to find the eigen values of $\mathbf A$, I feel that $0$ is an eigen value of multiplicity $ \geq 2$ since the repeated columns ($4-$th and $5-$th) results in two linearly independent eigen vectors $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R^7$ such that $\mathbf Ax_1=\mathbf Ax_2=0$. How to confirm the multiplicity of $0$ and the other eigen values?

I noticed that;

i. The matrix has a block form $\mathbf A=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf J_{3 \times 3}-\mathbf I_3 &\mathbf J_{3 \times 4} \\ \mathbf J_{4 \times 3} & \mathbf D_{4 \times 4}\end{pmatrix},$ where $\mathbf I_n$ is identity matrix of dimension $n$.

ii. $\mathbf A$ is symmetric.

Can we deduce some thing from the premises?

Comment: find the eigenvectors first.... this may be split into a 3 by 3  and a 4 by 4,   simply by taking eigenvectors with the last four elements zero,   then switching to the first three elements zero. The eigenvectors of your $J_{3,3}$  are the same as the eigenvectors of $J_{3,3}  - I,$  just the eigenvalues are shifted down.

Comment: someone posted the same problem 30 minutes ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4461249/how-to-find-the-permutation-matrix-so-that-the-given-symmetric-nonnegative-matri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Plan

Consider its block-wise structure,
$$
\mathbf A=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf J_{3 \times 3}-\mathbf I_3&\mathbf J_{3 \times 4} \\ \mathbf J_{4 \times 3} & \mathbf D_{4 \times 4} \end{pmatrix},
$$
It's straightforward to read the eigenvectors from the blocks than the whole matrix. So our strategy is to find the eigenvectors for diagonal blocks $\mathbf J_{3 \times 3}$ and $\mathbf D_{4 \times 4}+\mathbf I_4$. Then test if these are also eigenvectors for the whole matrix.

### $\mathbf J_{3 \times 3}$ block

For the $\mathbf J_{3 \times 3}$ block it could be written as $\mathbf J_{3 \times 3}=1_31_3^T$, which is a projection operator with vector $1_3$, it has eigenvectors $u_1=(1,1,1)^T$, $u_2=(0,1,-1)^T$, $u_3=(1,-1,0)^T$, with local eigenvalue $\mu_{1,2,3}=3,0,0$.

### $\mathbf D_{4 \times 4}$ block

Similarly, for $\mathbf D_{4 \times 4}$ block it's easy to construct its eigenvectors. $u_4=(1,1,1,1)^T$, $u_5=(1,1,-1,-1)^T$, $u_6=(0,0,1,-1)^T$, $u_7=(1,-1,0,0)^T$
with local eigenvalues $\mu_{4,5,6,7}=2,-2,0,0$.

### Augmenting local to global eigenvector

Then let's consider the non-diagonal blocks, since $u_{5,6,7}$ live in the right null space of $\mathbf J_{3 \times 4}$, $v_{i}=[0;0;0;u_i],i=5,6,7$ are eigenvectors of whole matrix $A+I$ and $A$.

With similar logic since $u_{2,3}$ live live in the right null space of $\mathbf J_{4 \times 3}$, $v_{i}=[u_i;0;0;0;0],i=2,3$ are eigenvectors of the whole matrix $A+I$ and $A$.

### Mixing eigenvectors of subspaces

Now we have found 5 eigenvectors for the whole matrix, since it's real symmetric we shall find another 2 eigenvectors with real eigenvalues. The remained subspace is spanned by the augmented vector of $u_1$ and $u_4$. $\tilde v_1=[1,1,1,0,0,0,0]^T,\tilde v_4=[0,0,0,1,1,1,1]^T$

Consider the action of $A+I$ restricted to the subspace $W=Span(\tilde v_1,\tilde v_4)$

$$
A+I|_{Span(\tilde v_1,\tilde v_4)}=\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
3 & 4\\
3 & 3
\end{array}\right)
$$
Easy to solve [this 2x2 system algebraicly](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=eig%5C%2840%29%5C%2891%29%5C%2891%293%5C%2844%29+4%5C%2893%29%3B%5C%2891%293%5C%2844%29+3%5C%2893%29%5C%2893%29%5C%2841%29),
$\mu_{1,4}=3\pm 2\sqrt 3$.
$$
v_1=\frac{2}{\sqrt 3} \tilde v_1 + \tilde v_4\\
v_4=-\frac{2}{\sqrt 3} \tilde v_1 + \tilde v_4\\
$$

### All together

Now we have our 7 eigenvectors for $A$ and $A+I$, it's straigtforward to check their eigenvalues, let $\alpha=\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}$
$$
[v_1,v_4,v_2,v_3,v_5,v_6,v_7]=\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\alpha & -\alpha & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\alpha & -\alpha & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\alpha & -\alpha & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

The eigenvalues are $[\lambda_1,\lambda_4,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_5,\lambda_6,\lambda_7]=2+ 2\sqrt 3, 2-2\sqrt 3,-1,-1,-2,0,0$